# Android - Layout -> Textview Prototype

Tags: android, layout, textview

On my Android application I make an interface with about 10 *Textview* with the same properties except for their id.

So is it possible to make a *TextView* prototype which make me able to create 10 textview child's ?

My questions deals of *Textview*, but it's the same interogation as *LinearLayout*, *EditView*, etc

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set a common attributes as a  style or theme for the textviews

```
<style name="CustomTheme">     
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item> 
</style>
```

And you can set this style to your activity like

```
<textview android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

The docs from google will give moe idea and examples
    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Thank's, it's may be a great solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with textview prototype and use an LayoutInflater to inflate the prototype. For instance you can try something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_prototype, null);
textView.setId();
```

You can place this in a loop to fill all the 10 textviews :)

and the textview_prototype could look like:

```
<TextView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Comment: It's a Java solution, I forget to mension it and I apologize, but I would like a XML solution to respecte the Android philosophy : making all the interface on my xml files

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you want it all in XML is to provide the layout for the TextView (my_textview.xml)

```
<TextView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/textview" >
</TextView>
```

And then in the layout you want to use it in you use the `include` tag like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <include layout="my_textview.xml" android:id="@+id/firstTextView" />
  <include layout="my_textview.xml" android:id="@+id/secondTextView" />
  <include layout="my_textview.xml" android:id="@+id/thirdTextView" />
  ... Add as many as you want with different ID's ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Providing the id attribute in the include tag will override the id of the primary layout/widget in the layout you want to include.

Comment: it's a little bit confused to me, but if I correctly understand your solution it's may be the best solution. I will try that

Comment: What parts do you find confusing? I can try to elaborate those parts.

Comment: This solution needs two differents xml file if I understand ? Is it possible to do this :  `<LinearLayout>
  <include layout="toto" android:id="@+id/newTextviewId" />
... </LinearLayout>` in which *toto* is a TextView present on the same file ?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that. The TextView needs to be in a seperate file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't afford me to create files with low utility. thank you anyway

Comment: You realize that the solution I posted above only requires 1 more file? In the long run, you save lines of xml-code because you only have to declare the textview and it's properties once. I have edited my post to make this point more noticable. If you want the non-blobbing XML-solution - this is it.